# A course of Pure mathematics incorrect

Tags: proof-explanation, rational-numbers

I thought I'd go through 'A Course Of Pure Mathematics' by G H Hardy 
And I came to this part:

> If the reader will mark off on the line all
>   the points corresponding to the rational numbers whose denominators are
>   1, 2, 3, . . . in succession, he will readily convince himself that he can cover
>   the line with rational points as closely as he likes. We can state this more
>   precisely as follows: if we take any segment BC on Λ, we can find as many
>   rational points as we please on BC.
>   Suppose, for example, that BC falls within the segment A1A2. It is
>   evident that if we choose a positive integer k so that
>   k · BC > 1,
>   ∗
>   (1) 
>   and divide A1A2 into k equal parts, then at least one of the points of
>   division (say P) must fall inside BC, without coinciding with either B or C.
>   For if this were not so, BC would be entirely included in one of the k parts
>   into which A1A2 has been divided, which contradicts the supposition (1).
>   But P obviously corresponds to a rational number whose denominator is k.
>   Thus at least one rational point P lies between B and C. But then we can
>   find another such point Q between B and P, another between B and Q,
>   and so on indefinitely; i.e., as we asserted above, we can find as many as
>   we please. We may express this by saying that BC includes infinitely many
>   rational points.

But what is he talking about?? This is obviously not true. 
I drew a picture but for some reason I can't upload it so I'll just describe it.

Let A1A2 be 6 units long and BC 1 unit long. 
B will exist 3 away from A1 and C 4. 
Then let k = 2. 
This satisfies 2*BC > 1 because 2*1 > 1.

Now we divide A1A2 into 2 equal parts. 6 / 2 = 3 
So P will exist 3 units away from A1. But this corresponds with B.

I know he's right. Am I reading this wrong? This doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $A_1A_2$ has length $1$ by definition (which is OK, since aif $BC$ does not lie within such an interval, it contains an integer). If you prefer, replace $k\cdot BC > 1$ by $k\cdot BC > |A_1A_2|$, and the proof works without that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think " k · BC > 1"
should be

"k * BC > A1 A2".

Then
$\dfrac{A1\ A2}{k}
\lt BC
$.